# MySql create or update row with ip?

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql

I have a table with ips and a count of the amount of times the ip accessed a certain page. I want to add one to the count if a row exists with the ip, otherwise create a row with the ip and set the count to 1.

I tried

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ip,count) VALUES ('" + ip + "',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1;
```

But ip isn't unique or primary, so it just keeps creating rows with the same ip. I tried making ip unique, but it won't let me. When I try to create a text column and make it unique, phpmyadmin says `BLOB/TEXT column 'test' used in key specification without a key length`.

I'm alright with using two statements. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to use `UNIQUE` you'll have to normalize the table first with all the duplicates rows before you can run your `ALTER` to make the column `UNIQUE`.  Probably easiest to create a new table, `SELECT INTO` it with the aggregated results (e.g. `SUM` etc...), and then `DROP` the old table and rename the tmp table to the old table name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `ip` to `UNSIGNED INT`, create a `UNIQUE` constraint on it and use this:

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (ip, count)
VALUES  (INET_ATON($ip), 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
        count = count + 1
```

To retrieve the ip in dot-decimal notation (like `192.168.1.1`), use:

```
SELECT  INET_NTOA(ip)
FROM    mytable
```

You may also create a prefixed index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_mytaable_ip ON mytable (ip(15))
```

but using `INT` column to store an ipv4 address is preferred.

Comment: @Walkerneo: IPv4 address is in fact a 32-bit number. You may use `INET_NTOA` and `INET_ATON` to convert to and from dot-decimal notation.

Comment: @Walkerneo: yes. Try running `SELECT INET_ATON('123.156.78.8')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start out with a select. (A pseudo-codish answer - you'll need to adjust for your specific dialect.)

So do a

```
select count(*) from mytable
where ip = $ip;
```

If the returned count is greater than 0 do

```
update mytable
set count = count + 1
where ip = $ip
```

else

```
insert into mytable($ip, count, <other fields>...) values (ip, 1, <other values>...);
```