# MySQL procedure to create or update a row in a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to write a MySQL proc which takes `userId` and `userName` and does an insert or update into table `users` dependent on if a row exists where `users.userId = userId`

I saw a similar question here: [MySql create or update row with ip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253379/mysql-create-or-update-row-with-ip)

But I want to do this in a stored procedure and wondered if that gives any additional tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a stored procedure, you can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Assuming that userid is the `PRIMARY` or a `UNIQUE` key, this will work:

```
INSERT INTO user
SET 
userid = ?,
userName = ?
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
userName = VALUES(userName)
```

Of course, you could wrap this query in a stored procedure if you want:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS set_user;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE set_user(
    IN i_userid INT UNSIGNED,
    IN v_userName VARCHAR(50)
)
DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user
    SET 
    userid = i_userid,
    userName = v_userName
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    userName = VALUES(userName);
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I prefer it to be a stored proc though... would I simply wrap that in a procedure body to get what I want?

Comment: Simply to decouple DB structure from code... we might want to do other things later, the DB might change, etc.